# Framework7, Firebase, VueJS Routes RequireAuth

Tags: firebase, vue.js, routes, firebase-authentication, html-framework-7

This is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Framework7 from 'framework7/dist/js/framework7.js';
import Framework7Vue from 'framework7-vue/dist/framework7-vue.js';
import Routes from './routes.js';
import App from './app.vue';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
Vue.use(Framework7Vue, Framework7);

var config = {

};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<app/>',
  framework7: {
    id: 'io.framework7.testapp',
    name: 'Framework7',
    theme: 'auto',
    routes: Routes,
  },
  components: {
    app: App
  }
});

console.log(Routes)

Routes.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  console.log()
})
```

I tried for a few hours now to implement that a user needs to be Authenticated before he can enter the Home View. Otherwise he will be redirected to the login View.

Maybe anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The following changes to your `main.js` file should normally do the trick. (I don't know however, if the framework7 framework interacts with the router and may cause problems).

You use `router.beforeEach()` to check if the "target" needs the user to be authenticated (based on `requiresAuth` meta). If the user is not authenticated you need to redirect her/him to the signin page. For that you can use `firebase.auth().currentUser`. See the corresponding Firebase doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentUser).

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Framework7 from 'framework7/dist/js/framework7.js';
import Framework7Vue from 'framework7-vue/dist/framework7-vue.js';
import Routes from './routes.js';
import App from './app.vue';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

Vue.use(Framework7Vue, Framework7);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

var config = {

};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const router = new VueRouter({
  Routes,
  mode: 'history'
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record  => record.meta.requiresAuth)
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser

    if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
        next('/signin')
    } else if (requiresAuth && currentUser) {
        next()
    } else {
        next()
    }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<app/>',
  framework7: {
    id: 'io.framework7.testapp',
    name: 'Framework7',
    theme: 'auto',
    routes: VueRouter,
  },
  components: {
    app: App
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respnonse. Now i get the following error in the console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: vue.common.js:580 [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "f7Ready": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

(found in <Root>)

Comment: I am afraid this comes from the framework7 framework which I don't know at all. As I said in the beginning of my answer, this framework may interact directly with the router and prevent the solution I proposed to work. I'm afraid I cannot help you anymore, sorry.

Comment: Does that helps? https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-vue/issues/318

Comment: Sadly not. I changed my main.js back to it original state. At this point i am able to log the Routes in the Console with console.log(Routes). 
But the Following code send the error "_routes2.default.beforeEach is not a function". Code: 
Routes.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  console.log()
})

Comment: So if you uncomment `let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;` you get the error about the length, right?

Comment: The lenght error is only not there if i undo all the changes you done...

Comment: I edited my code from the Question. There you can look what i mean.

Comment: How do you use firebase.auth in your code? I mean in other parts, i.e. the component that authenticate the user. Also, if I may, as you are a new contributor, it is better not to modify your initial question but rather update it by adding new elements. In such a way that future readers understand the entire discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Vue Router but the firebase way to do this is to wait for onAuthStateChanged method to trigger and track user state with this function.

To wait and get user state, i wrote a piece of code that you can call before changing route.

```
var user, authPromiseResolver, authPromiseResolved
var authPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  authPromiseResolver = resolve
})

var waitForUser = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    if(!authPromiseResolved){
      authPromise.then(resolve)
    } else {
      resolve(user)
    }
  })
}

firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
  user = firebaseUser
  if(!authPromiseResolved){
    authPromiseResolver(user)
    authPromiseResolved = true
  } 
})
```

`waitForUser` returns a promise who wait for first trigger of onAuthStateChanged (which will determine if an user is already logged in or not at page refresh), then resolve with user data or `null` it no user is logged in. So you just have to call this function before accessing each page :

```
waitForUser().then(function(user){
  if(user) {
    // An user is logged in
  } else {
    // Page unauthorized
  }
})
```

Each time the user state change (user logout/login), `user` variable will be set to `null` or with firebaseUser object and `waitForUser()` will always be resolved with the current user state